# Flask-SqlAlchemy: Insert model object that uses a sequence

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My model is defined as follows. Note that the ID column uses a server-side sequence.

```
class AgreementT(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'agreement_t'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'ets'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('ets.agreement_t_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    agreement_number = Column(Numeric)
    year = Column(Numeric(4, 0), nullable=False)
    ...
```

When I want to insert a record using Flask-SqlAlchemy, I need to fill out my model object first. But how do I specify that the ID column should be the default specified sequence?

```
@bp.route('submitAgreementForm', methods=['POST'])
def insertAgreementForm():
    req_json = request.get_json()
    form = req_json['form_values']

    # Prepare model object
    agreement = AgreementT(None, 'field1', 'field2', ...) # is 'None' correct for ID column?
```

Also, there is no default constructor for the model defined in `Agreement.py`. Is that ok?

Comment: You should be able to not pass anything for the `id`, as SQLA knows the server will provide a value.  So `AgreementT(field1='foo', field2='bar',...)`, not `AgreementT(id=42, field1='foo', field2='bar',...)`.

Comment: No constructor is fine.  By default SQLA calls [this function](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/c379f80b4e6fb1b65983958116bac202c91a210a/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py#L1129) to assign the keyword arguments.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67456528/5320906) of mine shows how to set up a custom constructor in flask sqlalchemy, if you don't like the default behaviour.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers.